# When tagging unrecognized faces on Facebook, tag gets re-assigned to nearest recognized face

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

I'm tagging people on photos on Facebook, but some faces are not recognized. I click on the photo and tag the person, it seems to put the square around the right face and tag it, but when the tag is saved, the damn Facebook thinks he is smarter than me and he erroneously reassigns the tag to the nearest face it can recognize. So the tag is reassigned to different face. This is very annoying. How to tell Facebook to stop to try being smart (=dumb) and just do  doing what it is told without any re-assignment?

Comment: File a bug with Facebook.

Comment: @phwd are you sure it's not a "feature"? I know, kind of sick "feature", but that's how it goes in many cases, unfortunatelly... the trend for the apps is to outsmart the user and offer even more "comfort" than the user wants :-)

Comment: A feature cannot be a feature if it's doing its purpose incorrect. The only way to "fix" (weakly held use of the word fix) outside of filing a bug is tagging the correct faces over an extended period of time and hope that Facebook picks up on the difference with whatever learning tool they use for tagging. https://www.facebook.com/help/191905394245544